# react-redux undefined from state when values are in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Getting bio, hobbies, createdAt, username, and image as undefined. Below is some of the code:

```
render() {
    const {
      selectedUser: { user: { bio, hobbies, createdAt, username, image },},
    } = this.props;
return ( 
    <div>
       <Typography variant="body1">{bio}</Typography>
    </div> 
);
}

User.propTypes = {
  selectedUser: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  selectedUser: state.data.selectedUser,
});
```

Am I supposed to do just selectedUser? If I do selectedUser { bio, hobbies, createdAt, ...}, the values don't show up so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

[image: image of state]

Comment: do you get `selectedUser` on the first render?
you might need to do `if (this.props.selectedUser === null) return null;`

Comment: In the reducer, in the `initialState`, does `selectedUser` have the same shape as what you're expecting in the component above?

Comment: You are destructuring this.props to **classes, selectedUser and UI**, but I don't see you mapping them to props except **selectedUser**.

Comment: Brian that worked - thanks! I took a look at it and it seems it was different.